# Piranha CMS Image Extenion in Custom Region

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, piranha-cms

I have created a custom Region and I now would like to add an Image to it.

How can implement the Image selector into this custom region?

I have seen an example [here](http://piranhacms.org/image-and-html-extensions) which shows you how to do this to the core extensions, but I can't seem to get it to work with a custom region.

```
public class AccordionItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

[Export(typeof(IExtension))]
[ExportMetadata("InternalId", "AccordionRegions")]
[ExportMetadata("Name", "Accordion")]
[ExportMetadata("ResourceType", typeof(Piranha.Resources.Extensions))]
[ExportMetadata("Type", ExtensionType.Region)]
[Serializable]
public class AccordionRegion : Extension
{
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public IList<AccordionItem> Items { get; set; }

    public AccordionRegion()
    {
        Items = new List<AccordionItem>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at your code and found a quite easy solution on how to incorporate images into your SlideItems. But first another thing.

```
[ExportMetadata("ResourceType", typeof(Piranha.Resources.Extensions))]
```

This meta data field is **only** valid if you want to fetch the key entered in the **Name** meta field to enable different languages based on culture. Since the key **Accordion** doesn't exist in the core it messes it up, at least for me.

Now onto the the image. To get it working I simply modified your slider item to the following:

```
public class AccordionItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public ImageRegion Image { get ; set ; }

    public AccordionItem() {
        Image = new ImageRegion() ;
    }
}
```

This way we can reuse the standard functionality from the ImageRegion that is available in the core project. Since you didn't provide the source code for your views I mocked them up like this.

**AccordionRegion.cshtml**

```
@model AccordionRegion

<ul class="form">
    <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
        <div class="input">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)</div>
    </li>
</ul>
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items)
```

**EditorTemplates/AccordionItem.cshtml**

```
@model AccordionItem

<fieldset>
    <legend>An item</legend>
    <ul class="form">
        <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
            <div class="input">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)</div>
        </li>
        <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Body)
            <div class="input">@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Body)</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    @Html.PartialFor("ImageRegion", m => m.Image)
</fieldset>
```

Since the ImageRegion renders quite a lot of HTML, I would implement some kind of server side code that generates a new AccordionItem and ships it back to the client with AJAX instead of hardcoding a lot of HTML/JS stuff in the view.